# CollectionView in TableView Cell Swift mix card type reuse issue

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

A collection view is contained in a table view cell.
Collection view cells are drawn for each card type.
In indexPath 0 and 1, the card is of a single type.
indexPath 2 is a mix type.
There are three card types, live reserved vod, and playLayer is added when it is a vod type.
When drawing collection view cells in mix type, playLayer is added to reserved type, and playLayer is added to all cells when scrolling up and down.

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

lazy private var homeManager = HomeManager()
var sections: [Section]?
var liveData: [Item]?
var vodData: [Item]?
var mixData: [Item]?

var table: UITableView = {
   let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.register(CardCollectionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CardCollectionTableViewCell.identifier)
   return tableView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    view.addSubview(table)
    homeManager.getdata{ [weak self] response in
        self?.sections = response.sections ?? []
        self?.liveData = self?.sections?[1].items ?? []
        self?.vodData = self?.sections?[2].items ?? []
        self?.mixData = self?.sections?[3].items ?? []
        
        self?.table.reloadData()
    }
    
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    table.frame = view.bounds
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        if indexPath.row == 0 && liveData != nil {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardCollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: liveData)
            cell.titleLabel.text = sections![1].title!
            return cell
        }  else if indexPath.row == 1 && vodData != nil {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardCollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: vodData)
            cell.titleLabel.text = sections![2].title!
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 && mixData != nil {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CardCollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionTableViewCell
            cell.configure(with: mixData)
            cell.titleLabel.text = sections![3].title!
           
            return cell
        }
        
        else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 400
}
```

CardCollection TableViewCell

```
static let identifier = "CardCollectionTableViewCell"

var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text16()
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

 var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
    return collectionView
}()

var models:[Item]?

func configure(with models: [Item]?) {
    
    self.models = models
    
    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.width.equalTo(300)
        make.height.equalTo(24)
    }
    
    collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(44)
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
        make.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    
    contentView.backgroundColor = .black
    
    //guard models != nil else { return }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
// Collectionview

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models?.count ?? 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.setupViews(with: models![indexPath.item])
    cell.setupConstraints(with: models![indexPath.item])
    cell.configure(with: models![indexPath.item])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 140, height: 350)
}
```

CollectionViewCell

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

static let identifier = "MyCollectionViewCell"

var player: AVPlayer?

private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.backgroundColor = .blue
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return image
}()

private lazy var typeLabelBackgroud: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return image
}()

private lazy var playerView: AVPlayerLayer? = {
   let url = URL(string: "https://1303309272.vod2.myqcloud.com/7e895809vodkr1303309272/8155555e3701925920462082823/f0.mp4")
    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 210)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.player?.play()
    }
   
    return playerLayer
}()

private lazy var typeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text10()
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

private lazy var timeLabel: UILabel? = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text11()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.frame.size.width = 42
    label.frame.size.height = 16
    return label
}()

private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = Fonts.text14()
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

private lazy var storeName: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text11()
    label.textColor = .gray
    return label
}()

private lazy var heartImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "Vector")
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return image
}()

private lazy var heartCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text11()
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.frame.size.width = 27
    label.frame.size.height = 16
    label.textAlignment = .left
    return label
}()

private lazy var eyeImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "Eye")
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return image
}()

private lazy var eyeCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = Fonts.text11()
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.frame.size.width = 27
    label.frame.size.height = 16
    label.textAlignment = .left
    return label
}()

private override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
}

public convenience init() {
    self.init(frame:. zero)

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
  
    
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

 func setupViews(with model: Item?) {
guard model != nil else {return}
print("CollectionViewCell의 model! data: \(model)")
    if model!.type == "LIVE" {
       addSubview(imageView)
       addSubview(typeLabelBackgroud)
       addSubview(typeLabel)
       addSubview(titleLabel)
       addSubview(storeName)
       addSubview(heartImage)
       addSubview(heartCountLabel)
       addSubview(eyeImage)
       addSubview(eyeCountLabel)
    } else if model!.type == "RESERVED"{
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(typeLabelBackgroud)
        addSubview(typeLabel)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(storeName)
        addSubview(heartImage)
        addSubview(heartCountLabel)
        addSubview(eyeImage)
        addSubview(eyeCountLabel)
    }  else if model!.type == "VOD" {
       addSubview(imageView)
       addSubview(typeLabelBackgroud)
       addSubview(typeLabel)
       addSubview(titleLabel)
       addSubview(storeName)
       addSubview(heartImage)
       addSubview(heartCountLabel)
       addSubview(eyeImage)
       addSubview(eyeCountLabel)
       addSubview(timeLabel!)
        imageView.layer.addSublayer(playerView!)
    }

}

 func setupConstraints(with model: Item?) {
 guard model != nil else {return}
    if model!.type == "LIVE" {
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(210)
        }
        
        typeLabelBackgroud.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(imageView).inset(8)
            make.top.equalTo(imageView).inset(10)
            make.width.equalTo(33)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        typeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(6)
            make.top.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(2)
            make.width.equalTo(21)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(imageView.snp.bottom).offset(8)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(42)
        }
        
        storeName.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(4)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(heartImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
        
        eyeImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(heartCountLabel.snp.trailing).offset(13)
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        eyeCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(eyeImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
        
    } else if model!.type == "RESERVED" {
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(210)
        }
        
        typeLabelBackgroud.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(imageView).inset(8)
            make.top.equalTo(imageView).inset(10)
            make.width.equalTo(33)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        typeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(6)
            make.top.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(2)
            make.width.equalTo(21)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(imageView.snp.bottom).offset(8)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(42)
        }
        
        storeName.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(4)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(heartImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
        
        eyeImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(heartCountLabel.snp.trailing).offset(13)
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        eyeCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(eyeImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
    } else if model!.type == "VOD" {
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(210)
        }
        
        typeLabelBackgroud.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(imageView).inset(8)
            make.top.equalTo(imageView).inset(10)
            make.width.equalTo(33)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        typeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(6)
            make.top.equalTo(typeLabelBackgroud).inset(2)
            make.width.equalTo(21)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        timeLabel!.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(imageView).inset(8)
            make.trailing.equalTo(imageView).inset(10)
           
        }
        
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(imageView.snp.bottom).offset(8)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(42)
        }
        
        storeName.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(4)
            make.width.equalTo(140)
            make.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        heartCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(heartImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
        
        eyeImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(heartCountLabel.snp.trailing).offset(13)
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.width.height.equalTo(16)
        }
        
        eyeCountLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(storeName.snp.bottom).offset(3)
            make.leading.equalTo(eyeImage.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
    }
}

    public func configure(with model: Item?) {
    //self.model! = model!
    
     guard model != nil else {return}
    if model!.type == "LIVE" {
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: model!.image!))
        typeLabel.text = "LIVE"
        typeLabelBackgroud.backgroundColor = .orange
        titleLabel.text = String(model!.title!)
        storeName.text = String(model!.store!)
        heartCountLabel.text = String(model!.likeCount!)
        eyeCountLabel.text = String(model!.playedCount!)
    } else if model!.type == "RESERVED" {
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: model!.image!))
        typeLabel.text = "예정"
        typeLabelBackgroud.backgroundColor = Colors.primary()
        titleLabel.text = String(model!.title!)
        storeName.text = String(model!.store!)
        heartCountLabel.text = String(model!.likeCount!)
        eyeCountLabel.text = String(model!.playedCount!)
    } else if model!.type == "VOD" {
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: model!.image!))
        typeLabel.text = "VOD"
        titleLabel.text = String(model!.title!)
        typeLabelBackgroud.backgroundColor = Colors.vodBackgroud()
        storeName.text = String(model!.store!)
        heartCountLabel.text = String(model!.likeCount!)
        eyeCountLabel.text = String(model!.playedCount!)
        timeLabel?.text = "01:35:40"
    }
}
```

}

The way I tried is let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout) ->
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout.init()) .
The reuse problem did not occur, but it cannot be used because the scroll direction is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve your problem in two ways:

1 - reset your cell in `cellForItemAt`

Currently you call `cell.setupViews(with: models![indexPath.item])` for each cell, which adds subviews to the cells. Since collectionView reuses cells, when scrolling you are getting cells which where used as all types (live, reserved, vod), that is why you see that "playLayer is added to all cells when scrolling up and down".

With this code you also add subviews each time the cell is reused, which is also not the best practice.

You could add an additional function to reset the cell and remove all subviews before adding new ones:

```
cell.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

(it is also better to add views to the `cell.contentView`)

2 - Create separate classes for different cell types

In `cellFroItemAt`you could check for the type of the cell and return the required on. Each type will have a different `ReuseIdentifier` and playLayer will be added only to the type you need

Comment: I add views to the cell.contentView.

Comment: In tableViewCell - yes, but not in collectionViewCell (i.e. addSubview(imageView) should be replaced with contentView.addSubview(imageView))

Comment: I corrected it. I added subview to contentview as you pointed out. Thanks.
but I curious of why.
and 
cell.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
I don't know where to add this code.

Comment: You could put it before ``cell.setupViews(with: models![indexPath.item])``.  Not it should be ``cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }`` due to updates

Comment: But this way you are losing all the performance benefits from cells reusing, so I suggest to use option 2

Comment: Okay, I'll try with option2. 
But before that, there is a method I tried. 
When it is not VOD type, replaceavplayercurrentItem: nil
How do you think about this solution?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by this method, could you update your question and add it?